# Can companies use code that I wrote during a coding interview in their products?

Tags: copyright, employment, licensing, copyright-transfer

Suppose a company's programmers are struggling to code a portion of a complex program. HR orders the questions of an upcoming interview to be replaced with that of the unfinished complex program. It is never mentioned in the new question's statement that the applicants are dealing with a real problem rather than an artificial one made just for the purpose of the interview.

Due to the high difficulty, only a handful of candidates successfully solved parts of the problem. While none of their solutions would complete the program alone, when combined they would make a nice solution. CEO decides to do just that but does not hire any of those interviewed, instead have the developers copy-paste then modify the answers those interviewed presented in order to cut costs. Can companies do this without giving any compensation to the code's original writers?

Comment: I know an independent video graphics designer who submits proposals to obtain commissions for TV productions. On more than one occasion has lost out, but later seen their ideas on screen. Whether or not it was a coincidence, it might be quite hard to prove the ideas were stolen. And after I submitted a CV to obtain a job, my exact phrases later appeared in the recruitment agency's advert to attract candidates, which hadn't been there before.

Comment: As a practical matter this simply isn't how software engineering is *done*, and it would waste far more time and money than it would save. For starters, if none of your engineers are qualified to come up with a solution, are they qualified to judge the correctness of applicants' solutions?

Comment: Unless you signed it and put a copyright notice on it, I think they are probably in the clear.  But it wont help them in the long run.

Comment: @Cadence for many problems in programming the correctness of a solution requires no engineering expertise whatsoever.  For example, if the problem concerns performance then anyone with a stopwatch might be able to judge the solution.  If the problem is identifying whether a given chess position is possible then engineering expertise is irrelevant.  And so on.

Comment: @RohitGupta copyright exists regardless of signature and copyright notice.  But the technical solution provided by the candidate isn't protected by copyright; copyright only protects the specific expression of that idea provided by the candidate.  If they express the same idea differently then they have not infringed the candidates copyright.

Comment: @Cadence If the root cause of the problem is that the staff engineers didn't know what they didn't know, then simply being shown a (partially) working solution would be of immense help.  As an analogy, have you ever failed in searching for something online, but only find the information after someone else mentions that you need to simply use *these* keywords?

Comment: "*HR orders the questions of an upcoming interview to be replaced*". That is odd. How much involvement does HR have in the company's strictly IT matters? Although a claim of copyright seems unlikely to succeed, candidates might have a viable claim of *fraud*.

Answer (score 0):

> CEO decides to do just that but does not hire any of those interviewed, instead have the developers copy-paste then modify the answers those interviewed presented in order to cut costs. Can companies do this without giving any compensation to the code's original writers?

Copying it verbatim and then making changes would be clear breach of copyright. The rights to that piece of code, *unless otherwise contractually agreed upon*, remain exclusively with the writer.

*However*, someone already mentioned, software development does not work that way. It would be absolutely fine to read all the candidates solutions, understand those solutions and then craft your own solution based on that.

That is why copying code from Stack Overflow verbatim is a problem (you would need to abide by the CC BY-SA license) while learning from it and then writing proprietary code with no attribution is fine and expected.

Copyright only protects the exact expression, not a vague idea.

For example were are allowed to make use of maths or the English language, despite the fact that we learned it in school from books that were copyrighted.

It would be a breach of copyright to copy those books, it is not when you simply use what you have learned from them.

Comment: Reading from it and learning from it also has the huge advantage that you learn something and that you can fix it if there are problems.